# Imdb iframe code not working

Tags: iframe, web, embed, imdb

I need to embed trailer from imdb in my application for that purpose i try to load this code which is provided by imdb officially.

```
<iframe src="http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi336244761//embed?autoplay=false&width=480" width="480" height="270" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It return back a black page. I don't know why is this not working, can you help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo with imdb api.
"http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi336244761//embed?autoplay=false&width=480"

It should be:
"http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi336244761/imdb/embed?autoplay=false&width=480"